# Multi-threaded python access seems synchronized

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a task where 10 threads each write 100 lines to a file at "the same time".  I had assumed the writes would be interleaved.  Instead it appears the writes are synchronized.  I am aware of the GIL but I did not believe it applied to file I/O as the underlying OS calls were outside the GIL.

```
import threading
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as named_temp:

    temp_filename = named_temp.name
    print(temp_filename)

    with open(temp_filename, mode='a') as writer:

        def thread_task(writer, thread_index):
            for iter_index in range(0, 100):
                writer.write(f'{(iter_index + thread_index * 100):06}')
                writer.write('\n')

        def make_thread(writer, thread_index):
            return threading.Thread(target=lambda: thread_task(writer, thread_index))

        threads = []
        for thread_index in range(0, 10):
            threads.append(make_thread(writer, thread_index))

        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

    with open(temp_filename, mode='r+') as reader:
        for line in reader.readlines():
            print(line, end='')
```

Is this to be expected or am I somehow setting this up incorrectly?  I am worried about the above code interleaving output (I don't mind the order of the lines but don't want something like `000007000008\n\n`.  So I am planning to introduce locking but before I do that I wanted to create a failing test and I am having trouble doing so.

This is on Python 3.6.8 if that is relevant.

Also, by "the writes are synchronized" I mean my output is `000001\n000002\n...000999\n` in perfect order.  At the very least I would expect out of order numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the writes are being buffered, so the GIL is not actually being released (it only gets released when the buffer is actually written out, which typically happens only when the buffer is full, or the file is explicitly `flush`ed or `close`d). Since the work done by each thread is pretty minimal, they never run long enough to release the GIL due to a timeout, and by never actually writing to disk, they never release it due to beginning a blocking system call.

If you make it `flush` for each line (or make the buffer small enough that a single thread fills it before finishing all its `write`s), you'll see interleaving as expected. One way to do so is to change:

```
with open(temp_filename, mode='a') as writer:
```

to:

```
with open(temp_filename, mode='a', buffering=1) as writer:
```

where `buffering=1` means line-buffered.

Comment: Wouldn't one want `buffering=0` to turn buffering off altogether?

Comment: @martineau: That'll work too, but the OP's case is writing lines, and line buffering limits it to interleaving lines (which is good enough for illustration), without interleaving characters (which is just confusing).

Comment: Doesn't `buffering=1` setting it to one byte or character, not one line?

Comment: @martineau: Nope. It's a special case; `-1` is default buffering, `0` is unbuffered, `1` is line-buffered, any other positive integer is a fixed buffer size.

Comment: Good to know. Where is that documented? I've been looking in the documentation and see stuff about `-1`, but so far haven't found it.

Comment: @martineau: On [the docs for the built-in `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). It's only valid in text mode (similarly, `buffering=0` is valid only for binary mode, which actually makes my claim about `buffering=0` being valid inaccurate, oops).